# Android espresso - cannot resolve allOf method for intended

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I'm learning how to UI testing with Espresso and I wanted to verify state of the intent. I'w written something like:

```
intended(allOf(
    hasAction(equalTo(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)),
    hasCategories(hasItem(equalTo(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE))),
    hasData(hasHost(equalTo("www.google.com"))),
    hasExtras(allOf(
        hasEntry(equalTo("key1"), equalTo("value1")),
        hasEntry(equalTo("key2"), equalTo("value2")))),
        toPackage("com.android.browser")));
```

But it gives me the compliation error:
[image]
That's the example from [here](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/). What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 9):

You can check full sample code here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/BasicSample/DialerActivityTest.java

Should work with next imports:

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.BundleMatchers.hasEntry;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasAction;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasCategories;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasData;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasExtras;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.toPackage;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.UriMatchers.hasHost;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.hamcrest.core.AllOf.allOf;
```